# How does it matter whether we stick the `<script>` tag in the head or not, assuming we’re already using `async` or `defer`?

Tags: javascript, browser, script-tag, web-performance

How does it matter whether we stick the `<script>` tag in the head or not, assuming we’re already using `async` or `defer`?

The script tag in question is for analytics. Apparently putting script tags anywhere else is [off-spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-head-element), but I don't care.

Comment: Async is quite new. Adding the js at the end of body was in preasync times...

Comment: @Jonasw afaik, async still has issues if you're loading libraries with dependencies.

Comment: @Beofett yep. But that has nothing todo with the question *should we put asyncly loaded code into body?*

Comment: @Jonasw true enough, but "adding the js at the end of body was in preasync times" kind of implies there is no reason to put the js at the end now.

Comment: @Beofett when using *async* no.

Answer (score 0):

As youve already pointed out, script tags belong to the header. The only reason to not do so was that scripts were loaded before the html was processed, causing a long waiting rendering. Thats why many people ignored the specs and embedded the scripts at the bottom. As this is not really a good way, the people writing the specs introduced *async* and *defer*. So no theres no reason to put asyncly loaded code into the body...

*Sidenote:* async and defer are not supported by all browsers yet. So may still use the old ( illegal ;) ) workaround...

Comment: 98% of USA browsers is pretty good! http://caniuse.com/#feat=script-defer